Was hoopoe in Leviticus and Deuteronomy mistranslated from the word for chicken?
I recently stumbled upon this comment made on a YouTube video
In Deuteronomy 14:17 of Aramaic Old Testament (also known as Aramaic Peshitta Tanakh), we see the words "Tarnagul Bara" which can be "literally" translated as "wild rooster" or "wild chicken." The word "Tarnagul" is masculine and it is translated as "rooster." "Tarnagul" can also mean "chicken" in general. Tarnagul's feminine form (in emphatic state) is Tarnagultha which is translated as "chicken" or "hen." The word "Bara" can be translated as "wild" (For example, "wild" honey in Matthew 3:4 of the Original Aramaic New Testament known as Aramaic Eastern Peshitta). I also want to point out that the Aramaic word "Anpa" (translated as hoopoe) is already mentioned in Deuteronomy 14:16 of the Aramaic Old Testament. So "Tarnagul Bara" cannot be "hoopoe." Below is my translation of
Deuteronomy 14:16, 17 (of Aramaic Old Testament).
"And stork (or heron) and hoopoe with their"
Now I did look up some interesting facts on the Peshitta. It is often disputed by Syrian churches as one of the most accurate and early versions of the NT. I couldn’t find anything in the OT, but I did look up the verses in Peshitta via BibleHub, and it did say “male chicken” in place of hoopoe. I also learned that the Rabbis interpreted this distinction of the unclean birds as one based on “scavenging and carnivorous”, which doesn’t seem to hold up well considering chickens and turkeys are also scavengers.
I’m a little confused now because I can’t tell if the inclusion of chickens as clean was manmade or legit. It also makes more sense that the OT was never claimed to be written ever in Aramaic and mainly in Biblical Hebrew, so that’s something to think about. I’ve seen multiple modern translations range from hoopoe to desert cock to grouse to lapwing, so honestly I wouldn’t be surprised if it could’ve meant chicken too.
“The Hebrew word is dukiphath, and various interpretations have been proposed for it, some taking it to be the common domestic fowl, others the cock-of-the-woods, or capercailzie, while others have preferred to translate it as Hoopoe. The Jewish Bible retains the word lapwing but adds the mark of doubt. Commentators are, however, agreed that of all these interpretations, that which renders the word as hoopoe (Upupa Tops) is the best.”
There is a lot of doubt behind the use of hoopoe and one of the possible translations in Hebrew is the chicken…
Some other interesting sources I’ve researched include:

Disagreement over the rooster in Peter’s Denial being a real rooster
“Some have cast doubt over the story of the cock crowing, claiming that according to the Mishna, the Jews were forbidden to breed hens or roosters in Jerusalem. Others have argued that the crowing of the rooster referred to the night-time vigils and that the third one was from midnight to three in the morning. “

Dead Sea Scroll and Mishna prohibition of raising chickens in Jerusalem
“t “They may not raise chickens in Jerusalem on account of the holy things [i.e., sacrifices], and priests may not raise them in the Land of Israel because of purity,” (m. Bab. Kam. 7:7). A prohibition against raising chickens in Jerusalem is also mentioned in the Dead Sea Scrolls (11QTc [11Q21] 3 I, 1-5).”


Does anyone have insight on this?

Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and how it is different than others. I also recommend going through the Help Center's sections on both asking and answering questions.

If chicken was an unclean bird, its eggs too would be unclean. Then, why did  Jews  rear chicken, as is evident from Jesus talking about hen protecting it's chicks. Was the rooster reared o nly to tell the time at sunup  and before ?

Hoopoe is the National Bird of Israel, suggesting that it was available in plenty in OT times. As per a Jewish tradition, hoopoe was instrumental in the rendezvous of Solomon and the Queen of Sheba. The diet of the hoopoe is mostly composed of insects, although small reptiles, frogs and plant matter such as seeds and berries are sometimes taken as well. It is a solitary forager which typically feeds on the ground. More rarely they will feed in the air, where their strong and rounded wings make them fast and manoeuverable, in pursuit of numerous swarming insects. More commonly their foraging style is to stride over relatively open ground and periodically pause to probe the ground with the full length of their bill. Insect larvae, pupae and mole crickets are detected by the bill and either extracted or dug out with the strong feet. Hoopoes will also feed on insects on the surface, probe into piles of leaves, and even use the bill to lever large stones and flake off bark ( Courtesy: Wikipedia ) .Eating habits of domestic chicken are different. They can survive on grains and
forage on earthworms for protein. If hoopoe was  forbidden as food item, it would also serve the purpose of protection of environment and biodiversity.
< In today's world, translation of names look easy with a lot of things like pictures of the object, coming handy  to the translator. It was not so in the early years of translation, all the more because flora and fauna differed from one geographical location to another. Eskimos have hundreds of words for ice , which English speaking people may find unnecessary ! Incidentally, one  version of Deuteronomy 14 in my native language Malayalam ( translated from Peshitta)  presents  the word in your question to mean 'forest chicken' .

Thank you so much for your insight! I do have to ask, since the modern chicken today was just a domestication of the junglefowl (which seems pretty close to what a “forest chicken” is), couldn’t you say this matches the description of what the Peshitta was attempting to describe? What does Malayalam consider to be a “forest chicken”?

Thanks Lenicia Jones for the appreciation. Malayalam is the language spoken by Orthodox Christians and Roman Syrian Christians who trace their faith to St Thomas the Apostle. Their ancient prayer books are in Syriac. Oldest versions of NT they have were originally translated from Syriac. Presently, there are many versions translated from English. Now, the jungle fowl or forest chicken, is hard to come by and is a protected species. As for the rooster that 'awakened' Peter 's   conscience, it must have been rared in High Priest's house where Jesus was tried.

Ahh okok! So I don’t know how Roman Syrian Christians teach food laws (if they are abolished or not) but do yall teach that the forest chicken/jungle fowl is an unclean animal? Wouldn’t all descendants be unclean as well, including the common chicken? For that case, since all pigs today aren’t the same species of swine in the Bible, then they’d be clean

Well Indian Christians generally follow Mk 7:15 which says : "There is nothing that enters a man from outside which can defile him; but the things which come out of him, those are the things that defile a man." The only laws they are afraid of are the civil laws on protection of endangered species. Chicken per se is not one. Junglefowl is ! To my understanding, Jews settled in Cochin of Southern India do eat chicken on special days, to assist in  which they bring Kosher experts from Israel.
